# Date Formatting Textbox

Tags: java, date, formatting, javafx

Is there a way to have a textbox that validates with the format **dd/mm/yyyy** and doesn't allow any other characters? I've managed to validate it so it's only numbers but having numbers and slashes is proving to be an issue.

I am using **JAVAFX**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a date control which is based on a textbox: https://github.com/nablex/jfx-control-date/
It allows you to set a format (supported by SimpleDateFormat) and supports a popup for mouse selection.

You can also enter values by typing (only valid values are allowed) and browse the fields with the arrow buttons (left & right will browse, up & down will increase/decrease).

Some example code (can also be found in the test class on github):

```
DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();

// you may not want the controls to manipulate time, they are on by default however
picker.setHideTimeControls(true);

// optional: the format you want the date to be in for the user
picker.formatProperty().setValue("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

// optional: set timezone
picker.timezoneProperty().setValue(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));

// optional: set locale
picker.localeProperty().setValue(new Locale("nl"));

// react to changes
picker.timestampProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Long>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Long> arg0, Long oldValue, Long newValue) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Filter logic was added. If you set a filter, you can limit the dates that are acceptable for the user to enter. Unacceptable dates will be greyed out in the GUI and the user will also be prevented from entering them manually in the text field.

For example this filter will block any dates before a random point in time:

```
    picker.filterProperty().setValue(new DateFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Date date) {
            SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try {
                return date.after(parser.parse("2010-07-13"));
            }
            catch (ParseException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how to use this with the javaFx? how to popup? which listener and which component is worked?

Comment: The DatePicker class extends TextField so you can use it wherever and however you would use a TextField. The popup is activated when you click it with the mouse but you could also have it popup when it is focused (this was actually initially the case but I myself rarely used the popup so I made it less intrusive). In the DatePicker class you can see on line 185 how the popup is activated on click.

Comment: @user1109519: Thanks and how to get selected date in console?

Comment: `picker.getDate()` gave me value of today but i want value which is I choose? then is it possible?

Comment: You can use "timestampProperty()" which is a long (due to immutability) or you can use the convenience method "DatePicker.setDate()" to set a custom date. There is also a setCalendar() convenience method. (note that the latter also updates the timezone though)

Comment: @user1109519: no man I want to select 5th of march then how to get selected date in console? from datepicker?

Is there any method available like pikcer.getselectedDate() or something which give me selected date in any format? long or anything?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. picker.getDate() will return whatever value is currently set by the user. If you want to initialize it to something other than the current date (which is the default) you need to use setDate() or update the timestamp property. Could you clarify what exactly you want to do that can not be done with these methods?

Comment: @user1109519: I get it man using your `timestampproperty listener` :) can I disable some dates to select from the user?

Comment: if use two datepicker in one form then how to restrict second datepicker?  for selecting date only after the dates which is select by first datepicker?

For Ex. I choose 10th jan 2014 then second date picker starting from
11th jan 2014 OR from starting to 10th jan 2014 all dates are disable in second datepicker?

Is it possible in this picker? as We can do it in Simple Core JAVA swing JDateChooser.

Comment: Hmm, there is currently no way to filter out specific dates though I can see why this would be a nice feature addition. It should be rather trivial to implement. Perhaps you can set a listener on timestampProperty and roll back any change that results in an invalid date? E.g.: if (isBlacklisted(newValue)) rollback(oldValue);

Comment: I haven't worked much with swing so I didn't know it had that feature. It should be implementable using the same logic I outlined in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks man and hope you enhance this feature soon. and there is no method found for isblacklisted and rollback?

Comment: @user1109519: nope man. this is the feature of jdatechooser component not the swing.. so we can't use that logic overhere.. I think setrange() is something like that?

Comment: I meant to say it is trivial to implement your own blacklisting. If you subscribe to changes from the timestampProperty() you can run **your own** isBlacklisted(newValue) method and if you determine that it is not valid, you can roll back the change. If you want to make the "validness" dependent on another date picker, this logic is trivial to implement in said custom isBlacklisted() method.

Comment: @user1109519: so we can disable button in this datepicker? using some logic code?

Comment: Ah ok you want to visually disable the dates. No this is not possible at this time without updating the control itself.

Comment: @user1109519: yeah I want to disable visually. Anyway thanks for your support and for effort. Really appreciated.

Comment: Because it is a nice to have feature, I added some code to enable a DateFilter. You can set it using the new filterProperty() of the DatePicker. It will enforce this filter when entering manually, using arrow keys or using the GUI.

Comment: @user1109519: have you added filtering code for disabling dates?

Comment: Yes, you can now use DatePicker.filterProperty() to set a DateFilter object. The DateFilter is an interface with an accept(Date) interface. An example is also included in the test file. It will visually disable unacceptable dates and prevent the user from entering it manually in the text field.

Comment: @user1109519: so I have to update my `Datepicker.java` file right? so where to get copy of your new file?

Comment: I would redownload the whole project. The test file was updated, DatePicker, the PopupCalendar and a new interface was added.

Comment: @user1109519:I redownload the whole project but it accept only string format? and I want to pass specific date or long format? then how it is possible?

Comment: Are you talking about the new filterProperty()? I shall add an update to the answer above.

Comment: @user1109519: hey its working with me. it disable all the date but it gives me stackoverflow error. first time it does not disable at the second time click on any date at that time listener will called and disable all dates..

Comment: Can you give me an example that is triggering the stack overflow? There are protections against stack overflow for invalid initial dates but perhaps I overlooked a specific case.

Comment: @user1109519: in the Datepicker `intialize()` when `textProperty().addListener` called `if (filter.getValue().accept(getDate())) setText(oldValue);` here error occurs..:(

Comment: hey is there any solution for this?
`@Override
 protected String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
  return DatePicker.class.getClassLoader().getResource("jfx-date-picker.css").toExternalForm();
 }` because everytime I manually pur css in classes. and when i close the editor and open it again I must put css again in that folder.. otherwise give me nullpointer exception :(

Comment: @user1109519: this is my listener. please check where I did mistake?  http://pastie.org/8865203

Comment: I don't see any particular problem with it, can you give me more information regarding the stack overflow?

Comment: I give you my code where i get error.. so check it at your side? can you disable the second datepicker dates? as per selection of first picker? when I am doing this it gives me that error.. and after two time click on the picker after that dates disable..

Comment: Instead of recreating a new date filter every time, would this not be better? http://pastie.org/8865225

Comment: @user1109519: Still having problem; it disable after clicking on any date.. so it set the selected date though it is not correct date..
For eg: I selected 15 jun in first picker and in second picker i can select 12 Jun  and after the select 12 Jun it disable starting to 14th June.. and in the text box incorrect value that is 12Jun :(

Comment: @user1109519: I solved this issue man. Using setDate(). Thanks.. but what about my css problem? can you give me solution for that?

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. I actually had completely missed your css comment but looking at it now I'm not sure what you mean. The css file mentioned here is available in the project so it should be in the jfx-date-picker.jar file and available. Why is it being removed?

Comment: what? where is the jar file of your project? I used your java file to serve my purpose?

Comment: No problem. I meant to say that in your final project you should not include the source code from github in your own jar but rather package the github code into its own jar and put it on the classpath. The resulting jar will contain the css file. (PS: you have to build the jar yourself, you can run "mvn package" to do this)

Comment: @user1109519: I can not get it what I am suppose to do? where to put your css file?

Comment: I use maven for lifecycle management. If you know and have maven you can easily run "mvn package" in the root folder which will result in a packaged jar that you can put on your classpath. If you don't have maven you will have to use your own environment to package it (e.g. export in eclipse). I would highly recommend reading up on maven, it doesn't take long to understand and it's immensely powerful.

Comment: @user1109519: okay man thanks.. I will go through the docs of using maven. at that putting css in the class folder manually..