# JavaFX good DateChooser need

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, datechooser

Need good DateChooser for JavaFX project(JDK 7).

I was faced with the task of which is the need to use DataChooser.

please recommend ready solutions, for implement and use it in JavaFX (JXML files)

Comment: Check these answers out: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546776](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546776) [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19371211](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19371211) [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19028232](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19028232).

Answer (score 3):

There's a new date picker in JavaFX 8.  It's all included in JDK 8.
https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

A cool little video on using it.
https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/javafx_8_datepicker_with_lambdas

Comment: If you plan to stay with 7 you could always incorporate the source from [OpenJFX here.](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/9fee2eb28a6e3b03a48ecd4b3b32582ebd0a7ac9/javafx-ui-controls/src/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.java?at=default)

Comment: @brian: I am also using JDK7 then how to use datepicekr? do you have a working example of datepicker? i used this http://edu.makery.ch/blog/2013/01/07/javafx-date-picker/ but not getting all event with this datepicker? :(

Comment: I'm using jdk 8 so I use the built in one.

Comment: @brian: but some methods and functionlity not work with jdk8 that's-why I used jdk-7. so is there any help for jdk7 datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

I found this very beautiful component for datepicker.. Check this if you running your javaFX application on JDk7.

Link for download [Datepicker](https://github.com/nablex/jfx-control-date/).

Reference for this picker. [Follow this instruction for working with Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19028232/2722799)

Thanks..